# MYSQL BETWEEN query only returning last result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So to my knowledge I have a pretty simple piece of php that has been breaking my back all day

```
  $startDate = "2016-07-27";
  $endDate = "2016-07-31";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publishersStatistics WHERE dataDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" . $startDate . "','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $endDate . "','%Y-%m-%d') ORDER by dataDate DESC");

  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);
```

The code is very simple and this is the entire document (other than database connection stuff) - It takes a start date and end date and finds all values in-between those two dates. However for some reason it's **only returning the last date in the query** (2016-07-31)'s information.

I have no idea why this is!

I have also tested using ASC instead of DESC, this returns the first result. (2016-07-28)'s information only! Does anyone have any idea why I seem to be able to **only recall one row?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` fetches __row__ and not __all rows__

Comment: **Stop** usind deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: Please [stop using the mysql_ functions as they have been removed from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! I've changed to mysqli_, is there a way to recall all rows that match the between statement in that case? Thanks again.

Comment: $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: @ashlewis please take a look on first comment it's your answer. u_mulder is right.

Comment: so...... do a *loop dah loop!* `while` you're at it. ;-) and *enjoy the ride!*

Comment: @kooKooDoneSlapHisWife `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` - the OP is using the MySQL_ API and not the MySQLi_ one, which are not compatible together.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP commented that they had changed it to msqli...

Comment: @kooKooDoneSlapHisWife I see the comment now; you're right. The OP needs to update their code in order to reflect what they are `NOW()` using. I smell "mixing MySQL APIs" at this point in time and/or probably still not looping over successful results.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to support the question, especially about the `ajax` tag and what is now being used, `mysqli_`. Remember this: The LESS we know, the MORE TIME it takes to provide you with a solution. I for one have hung around here long enough. See the answers given below.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_row() return one row , 
you can loop results by using

A) mysql_fetch_array() return array(0=>value,column=>value);

or

B) mysql_fetch_assoc() return array(column=>value) as you need in json..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array[] = $row;
}
 echo json_encode($array);
```

mysql is old and now all walk to mysqli

Comment: Did you read over the (new) comments under their question? Especially the one about: *"Thanks! I've changed to **mysqli_,** is there a way to recall all rows that match the between statement in that case? Thanks again. – ashlewis 15 mins ago"*

Comment: This works fine using mysql! Thanks :) I've changed to mysqli and that seems to be working either way but thanks for providing the mysql version just incase!